# Show only one select

Tags: jquery

I have a select box with different options. Based on which option you choose in the first one, an another select is shown below with other options related to the option you choosed in first place. The problem I have is that when you choose a different option in the first select, the other select below is not replaced with the new options based on the first option you choosed, instead, a whole new select form is shown with the options. The select duplicates itself.

Ass you can see, I have tried to use .empty(), but it does not work..

I hope you understand me :-)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_value = ''; 
    $('.type_of_connection').change(function() {
        selected_value = $(this).val();                     
        $('.content').not("#" + selected_value).hide();     
        $("#" + selected_value).fadeIn();                   
    });

    $('.supercustomer').change(function(evt) {
        $('#show_switch').empty();
        var supercustomer_id = $(this).val();   
      $.get('show_switch.php', {supercustomer_id: supercustomer_id}, function(html){
          $("#" + selected_value).append(html);
      }, "html");                                           //Använder ID:et på superkunden i show_switch.php för att hämta rätt switch 
    evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

show_switch.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['supercustomer_id']))
{
    include("../../include/dblayer.class.php");                     //Temporär lösning. När show_switch.php anrops, så finns inte $link tillgänglig. Därför finns detta.
    $link = new dbLayer("root", "", "localhost", "kundadmin");
    $supercustomer_id = $_GET['supercustomer_id'];
    $query_sw = "SELECT * FROM switch WHERE superkund_id=$supercustomer_id";
?>
    <div id="show_switch">
    <label name="switch">Switch:</label><select name="switch" class="switch">

        <?php

                while($row=$link->get_object($query_sw, 99)){
                    print'<option value="'.$row->switch_id.'"';
                    if($row->switch_id == $supercustomer_id)
                        print' selected';
                    print'>'.$row->gatuadresser.'</option>';
            }
    ?>
        </select>
        </div>  
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use somethink like this:

```
        $.getJSON('url', { id: dataId, rnd: Math.random() }, function (data) {

            $(target).empty();
            if (data != null) {

                var list = data.List;

                $.each(list, function (index, itemData) {
                    $(target).append($('<option/>', { value: itemData.Value, text: itemData.Text }));
                });
            }

            $(target).change();
        });
```

**EDITED:**

```
$('.supercustomer').change(function(evt) {
    var supercustomer_id = $(this).val(); 

$.getJSON('show_switch.php', {supercustomer_id: supercustomer_id}, function(html) {                
            $('#show_switch').empty();
            if (html != null) {
                var list = html.List;                    
                $.each(list, function (index, itemData) {
                    $('#show_switch').append($('<option/>', { value: itemData.Value, text: itemData.Text }));
                });
            }

            $('#show_switch').change();
        });                                             
evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: you should to return a dictionary with [value, text] pairs